# Derivative of a function defined by parts involving dirac delta

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta

Given a function $$\rho (x_1,x_2,x_3,t)=\begin{cases} \rho_1,\text{ if } x_3 \geq f(x_1,x_2,t) \\ \rho_2,\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
I found its gradient as
$$\nabla \rho = (\rho_2 - \rho_1) (\partial_{x_1}f(x_1,x_2,t),\partial_{x_2}f(x_1,x_2,t),-1)\delta(x_3 -f(x_1,x_2,t)).$$
Could anyone explain how is this obtained?

Comment: Are you asking for people to explain to you how you got this result?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is my question

Comment: You can write $\rho$ as $$\rho(x_1,x_2,x_3,t) = \rho_1 \mathbb{1}_{\{x_3 - f(x_1,x_2,t) \geq 0\}} + \rho_2 (1 -  \mathbb{1}_{\{x_3 - f(x_1,x_2,t) \geq 0\}})$$ and then formally differentiate it by saying that the differential of the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{\{x \geq 0\}}$ is the dirac $\delta(x)$ and then apply the chain rule.